# Problem with Laravel Livewire : Attempt to read property "recipes" on array

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to do a search input from 2 datatables of my database, one containing vegetables and the other one containing recipes made of vegetables, i first made my search input with only the elements from the vegetable table. But now im trying to include the repice table but it wont work: I'm getting the error "Attempt to read property "recipes" on array" but I do't understand where the problem comes from.

This is my code:

Search.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Vegetable;

class Search extends Component
{
    public $query = '';

    public $vegetables;
    public $recipes;

    public function updatedQuery() 
    {
        $this->vegetables = Vegetable::where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->query.'%')->get()->toArray();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.search');
    }
}
```

search.blade.php :

```
<div class="searchcomponent">
    <h1>Recherche</h1>
    <input wire:model="query" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher...">
    
    @if(!empty($query))
        <ul>
            @if(!empty($vegetables))
                <div class="vegetables">

                    @foreach($vegetables as $vegetable)
                        <li><span class="material-icons">lunch_dining</span>{{ $vegetable['name'] }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                
                </div>
            @else
                <li>Pas de résultat</li>
            @endif
            
            <div class="recipes">

                @foreach($vegetables as $vegetable)
                    @foreach($vegetable->recipes as $recipe)
                        <li><span class="material-icons">menu_book</span>{{ $recipe['name'] }}<span class="ingredient">Ingrédient: {{ $vegetable['name'] }}</span></li>
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </ul>
    @endif
</div>
```

My model Vegetable :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vegetable extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function recipes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class, 'vegetables_recipes', 'vegetable_id', 'recipe_id');
    }

    public function getName($id) {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

My model Recipe :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Recipe extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function vegetables(){
        return $this->hasOne(Vegetable::class, 'vegetables_recipes', 'recipe_id', 'vegetable_id');
    }

    public function getName($id) {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

The model from my pivot table VegetablesRecipe :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class VegetablesRecipe extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['vegetable_id', 'recipe_id'];
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sidenote, the opposite of a `belongsToMany()` is another `belongsToMany()`; right now, you have it set as a `hasOne()`. That doesn't seem right. As for your error, `foreach($vegetable->recipes as $recipe)` should maybe be `foreach($vegetable['recipes'] as $recipe)`. "Attempt to read property "recipes" on array" means you're using Object Access `->recipe` on an Array, which expects array access `['recipes']`. Models in Laravel should allow both, i.e. `->recipes` and `['recipes']` should both work, unless you are (or Livewire is) doing something to override that logic.

Comment: Oh thanks ! I understand the error now ! 
As for the belongsToMany, I changed it, i don't really remember why i initially put a hasOne.....
So i tried to edit my code and now i got a "Undefined array key "recipes" "error. I guess it means the program can't find the field reciped in my vegetables model?

Comment: Ah, cause you're calling `->toArray()` in your `Search.php`; remove that and your code should work with either `->recipes` or `['recipes']`. When you transform a Collection of Models to an array, they lose all non-loaded relationship accessors. Additionally, you typically don't define a Model for your Pivot table; the `VegetablesRecipe` Model can be removed, or kept around if you ever need to query that table directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the issue with your code; I didn't notice it yesterday as it was hidden off-screen in your `Search.php`'s `updatedQuery()` function:

```php
$this->vegetables = Vegetable::where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->query.'%')
->get()
->toArray();
```

When you call `->toArray()`, you convert the Collection of `Vegetable` Model instances into an Array of Arrays. This means you cannot use Object Access to get Properties:

```php
$vegetable->recipes; // Fails with error "Attempt to read property "recipes" on array"
```

Additionally, you cannot access any Model functions, as an Array is not an instance of a Model:

```php
$vegetables['recipes']; // Undefined array key "recipes"
```

Since `public function recipes()` is a method of the `Vegetable.php` Model class, that won't work. It *can* work, if you load it first *before* casting to an Array:

```php
$this->vegetables = Vegetable::where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->query.'%')
->with('recipes')
->get()
->toArray();
```

Now, `$vegetable['recipes']` will work, but it's better to just drop the `->toArray()` completely:

```php
$this->vegetables = Vegetable::where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->query.'%')
->with('recipes')
->get();
```

Additionally, for performance reasons, you want to include `->with('recipes')` to prevent N+1 queries being called while looping.

With those changes made, you can write your `livewire/search.blade.php` code as follows:

```
<div class="searchcomponent">
  <h1>Recherche</h1>
  <input wire:model="query" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher...">
  @if(!empty($query))
    <ul>
      @if(!empty($vegetables))
        <div class="vegetables">
          @foreach($vegetables as $vegetable)
            <li><span class="material-icons">lunch_dining</span>{{ $vegetable->name }}</li>
          @endforeach
        </div>
      @else
        <li>Pas de résultat</li>
      @endif
      <div class="recipes">
        @foreach($vegetables as $vegetable)
          @foreach($vegetable->recipes as $recipe)
            <li><span class="material-icons">menu_book</span>{{ $recipe->name }}<span class="ingredient">Ingrédient: {{ $vegetable->name }}</span></li>
          @endforeach
        @endforeach
      </div>
    </ul>
  @endif
</div>
```

Lastly, some cleanup:

`Vegetable.php` and `Recipe.php`

The methods `getName($id)` have no purpose; you're not doing anything with `$id`, and `name` is not a private property; you can simply do `$vegetable->name` or `$recipe->name` and it will do the same as what these methods are doing.

`Recipe.php`

As stated in the comments, `belongsToMany()` is the inverse of `belongsToMany()`, not `hasOne()`:

```php
public function vegetables(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Vegetable::class, 'vegetables_recipes');
}
```

Additionally, if the primary and foreign key names match the model names, you don't need them. The proper name for the pivot table would be `recipes_vegetables` (plural, alphabetical), so specifying that is required. You can do the same for `Vegetable.php`:

```php
public function recipes(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class, 'vegetables_recipes');
}
```

Lastly, your model `VegetablesRecipe.php` is not needed, and is currently not being used. You typically don't define a Model for a Pivot table, so you can either remove it, or keep it around should you ever need to directly modify the Pivot.

Comment: Oh there's one problem still, the way you made it doesnt allow me to search a specific recipe, it's only gonna search a recipe via the ingredients that are linked to this one, but what if i also want the query to send me the results of the recipes table? I've tried to make it with an inner join and by adding a new recipes variable in the componenet, but it still won't send me the results from the other table..... any idea why? thank you

Comment: Hmm, not too sure; I'd need to see some code. Please consider asking another question (after trying some implementation yourself of course) and including all your coding attempts and a clear error message there.

Comment: Alright :) will do ! thanks for your help again !!